# JQuery Passing values into .Each() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a pretty simple (Well simple to the point that I am not sure how to make it work) little issue.
I have an object that contains an array of data that I need to utilize inside my each statement and to my surprise... I can't just directly reference it. I have read that specifying an

```
var something = this;
```

before the if would allow it to be called and that was no good.

> Current Code:

```
var exsistingshifts = response.data.ExsistingEvents;
var eventdata = this;
$(".shiftdiv").each(function (index) {
   var currdiv = $(this).children();
   var info = eventdata.exsistingshifts;
})
```

Expected result info = my array of delicious data

Current result info = undefined

For people wanting Context, shiftdiv class divs are built dynamically by a query and have a data value in their ID that link them to a certain set of events. The array contains ALL events and their data keys, so for each shift div I need to capture the ID which is easy enough, compare it to the array and pluck out the values I need from that array to mess with that particular div.

As for page context of the $(this) this is being called inside of an onclick function. The onclick function sets response.data.ExsistingEvents

Comment: Try `var eventdata = $(this);`

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. We do not know e.g. what is `this` that is being assigned to `eventdata`.

Comment: `$(".shiftdiv").each` will loop through each elements present inside it. What  
 do you need actually?

Comment: @JayeshChitroda - Did see that, my bad but still no. Doesn't like that.

Comment: Added context notes for those that wanted them

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to access `exsistingshifts` from inside the each loop? that's it?

Comment: I don't think you understand how property access is working in this case. `eventdata.exsistingshifts` is just looking for the value of the property `exsistingshifts` that is expected to be inside `eventdata`. It has nothing to do with your variable defined above. Since `eventdata` is `this`, and `this` is an onclick function. That `this` refers to the element being clicked, which doesn't have a property called `exsistingshifts`.

Comment: If I understood correctly: you don't need `var eventdata = this;`. You can just access the variable name inside the anonymous function (javascript pass outter scope to inner scope automatically). Try `console.log(exsistingshifts);` inside your each function and you should see the variable content in the console.

Comment: @mrlew I tried that one at the beginning thinking it would be that easy. The outcome - exsistingshifts is not defined(…)

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/0ts4jwwv/ (just to show you) . Your problem seems to be another thing (maybe your data is not being populated).

Comment: Gave that a look and yours seems to work, I just looked at what $(this) returns inside my each loop and I get the Window Element. If I break point right before the .each() loop the data is all there and happy, as soon as I enter the loop... Gone

Comment: It's hard to figure out without checking the related code. Can you create a fiddle or post more code?

Comment: @mrlew can do - Not sure how much help it will be as it won't run without all of the API's in place but for contextual purposes here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/caz1224/L8Lfjgzj/

Comment: Checking your fiddle, you can certainly access response object inside your each. Tip: do a `console.log(response.data);` inside your `$(".shiftdiv").each(function (index) {` and check if the content is there.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , you are using this code inside ajax Success function (I can see response object so.)

Now if you are doing so, you are doing a mistake by assigning `this` object to `eventdata`.

line `var eventdata = this` will store $.ajax object in eventdata, 
and `this` object (means that your ajax object) doesn't contain any value for key `exsistingshifts` , So `eventdata.exsistingshifts` is undefined.

change your code to following should work

```
$(".shiftdiv").each(function (index) {
  var currdiv = $(this).children();
  var info = response.data.ExsistingEvents[index].exsistingshifts;
});
```

Comment: Correct about the AJAX side of things, unfortunately calling  response.data.ExsistingEvents inside the loop results in response is not defined(…)

Comment: That is because you have assigned `this` to `eventdata`. `eventdata` is global to `.each()` method . so if you wrote `eventdata = response.data...`, that would work. and if you do `console.log(eventdata)` inside `.each()` loop, You will find that this is an ajax object (without key exsistingshifts).